# Jquery calling my wcf web service. How to view the returned json?

Tags: jquery, wcf, web-services

So I have my web service which is a WCF and it supports JSON. 
When i enter this url 
 http://localhost/HelloWorldWebService/HelloWorld.svc/getperson 
 in my browser it returns 
 {"GetPersonResult":{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}}

Now I have the following jquery:

```
function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../HelloWorldWebService/HelloWorld.svc/getperson",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
     }

     $(document).ready(function () { CallService(); });
```

it shoes the success pop-up ... 
how can I show the content of the msg in my pop-up? 
I tried alert(msg) but it shows [object Object] ???

EDIT: This is what i get when using Firebug with console.log(msg)
[image]

So how do I access the FirstName to display it in the alert?

EDIT:

So finally found out how the syntax works. So to get the firstname I had to do 
alert(msg.GetPersonResult.FirstName);

Comment: You can use firebug firefox plugin. Than you will see, what you sent, what you received and all headers.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the object that you get back?   it's saying [object Object] because it's an object not a string,    to see it you can use something like firebug, or perhaps fiddler,  but i doubt what you actually want to do is alert it...

Comment: I used fiddler and i do see HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 57
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2011 17:11:47 GMT

{"GetPersonResult":{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}}

Comment: For starter i just want to alert it. Just for education purpose, trying learn how all these web tech works, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging it to the console, so you can see the properties returned by the "msg" object.  You can then output the data.

```
console.log(msg);
```

It will output your msg object, you can then access variables such as msg.data if that is what it returns.

Comment: I added console.log and use firebug, check my edited post. when I do alert(msg.data) i get undefined ..? Sorry for my noobness .. all of this is really new to me.

Comment: Well, I was just saying .data as an example, if you look at the console, it should be showing you an object named msg.  This object has properties, you can then access those properties.  So say it has a property called name.  You would alert it out like this  alert(msg.name)  I don't know what properties it's returning to you, but the console will show you that.

Comment: I see. so it knows the whole structure of the object that has been returned ... hmm interesting.

Comment: finally got it to work with your guidance thanks. i had to do alert(msg.GetPersonResult.FirstName); Thanks!